# InsecurePlatformWarning when web scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I am using Python 2.7.6 to get data from different sites, but some websites give `insecurePlateformWarning` and refuse to give their data. I want to know how to remove the warning.

Comment: Copy paste the exact error string here. What is the website giving the error? Give us more information

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation page](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning) for `urllib3` explicitly advises you to do one of the following, in case of an `insecurePlateformWarning`

> - upgrade to a newer Python version
> - upgrade ndg-httpsclient with pip install --upgrade ndg-httpsclient
> - use pyOpenSSL as described in the OpenSSL / PyOpenSSL section

You are using Python 2.7.6 so I guess the first item may be applicable here. From the same page, see:

> Certain Python platforms (**specifically, versions of Python earlier
>   than 2.7.9**) have restrictions in their ssl module that limit the
>   configuration that urllib3 can apply.

In short, you should try to upgrade to Python 2.7.9 at least, or upgrade `ndg-httpsclient` as described.